# Adding Maven Dependencies in Intellij

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea

How can I add the below two Maven dependencies to my Intellij android project?

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

From what I've read, it appears that I need a pom.xml file. Perhaps I should first add maven to the project in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use Android Studio, then you can add those two lines to the `build.gradle` in your `app` folder

There is a place for adding dependecies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
}
```

Then clean and rebuild the project and you are done.